# paho-mqtt connecting to broker with self-sign

Tags: ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, paho

I am trying to connect python client (`paho-mqtt 1.5.0`) to mosquitto broker (self-signed certificate). Connecting using MQTT.fx with TLS certs works.
But when I tried to connect using python client with this code ([full code](https://pastebin.com/raw/5EUPX70c))

```
mqtt_client.username_pw_set(mqtt_username, password=mqtt_password)
mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
mqtt_client.on_publish = on_publish
mqtt_client.tls_set(ca_certs=TLS_CA_CERT, certfile=TLS_CLIENT_CERT,
                    keyfile=TLS_CLIENT_KEY, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                    tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)
mqtt_client.tls_insecure_set(False)
mqtt_client.connect(broker_endpoint, port=port)
mqtt_client.loop_start()
```

I got following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "device.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "device.py", line 88, in main
    if not connect(mqtt_client, MQTT_USERNAME,
  File "device.py", line 55, in connect
    mqtt_client.connect(broker_endpoint, port=port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 937, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1100, in reconnect
    sock.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

Logs from broker

```
1586374114: New connection from 20.4.32.278 on port 8883.
1586374114: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14035418:SSL routines:ACCEPT_SR_CERT:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
1586374114: OpenSSL Error[1]: error:140350E5:SSL routines:ACCEPT_SR_CERT:ssl handshake failure
1586374114: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

As per [this](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/123) issue I changed my code

```
mqtt_client.tls_set(ca_certs=TLS_CA_CERT, certfile=TLS_CLIENT_CERT,
                    keyfile=TLS_CLIENT_KEY, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,
                    tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)
mqtt_client.tls_insecure_set(True)
```

With this one I am able connect to broker. But first attempt of the script fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "device.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "device.py", line 88, in main
    if not connect(mqtt_client, MQTT_USERNAME,
  File "device.py", line 55, in connect
    mqtt_client.connect(broker_endpoint, port=port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 937, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1100, in reconnect
    sock.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error
```

I see this error on brocker side

```
1586379530: New connection from 20.4.32.278 on port 1883.
1586379530: Client <unknown> disconnected due to protocol error.
```

Second attempt of the script with no changes works & client connects on port

```
1586379710: New connection from 20.4.32.278 on port 8883.
1586379710: New client connected from 20.4.32.278 as auto-697CC441-83F5-7F50-6DF8-E85F96DEA1D7 (p2, c1, k60, u'.device.dev.lightcloud.com').
```

Trying to understand why client on connect on port `1883` first time and fails then conect on port `8883` second time and succeeds.

with `cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE` & `tls_insecure_set(True)` client will have complete insure connection with broker ? Is it safe to use it in non-production environment ?

Comment: any idea what went wrong?